# Pointer Example in Textbook is confusing me

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm currently going over pointers in class and our textbook is confusing me a little bit.  They start off by saying that following example copies the value in the place pointed to by money into the place pointed to by myMoney:

```
*myMoney = *money;
```

Then the next example copies the value in money into myMoney

```
myMoney = money;
```

This second example causes a memory leak because the original location that *myMoney pointed is no longer accessible.  Is this because the memory that used to hold the pointer is now an actual float value instead of a memory address?

Now the part that confuses me a little is in the next part when they are showing a different declaration.  Full example:

```
char alpha[20];
char *alphaPtr;
char *letterPtr;
vod Process(char []);
.
.
alphaPtr = alpha;
letterPtr = &alpha[0];
Process(alpha);
```

Since the book says that

```
myMoney = money;
```

will create a memory leak because it severs the link between the pointer and it's pointed to address, will

```
alphaPtr = alpha;
```

cause a memory link also?  Shouldn't they have declared it like

```
char *alphaPtr = *alpha;
```

Comment: I just wanted to thank all you guys for the help you've provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to remember:

- `myMoney` and `money` are pointers, so `myMoney = money;` copies one pointer *over* another. Now you have two pointers pointing at the same thing (what `money` pointed to), and nothing pointing at what `myMoney` used to point at (this is a memory leak).
- `*myMoney` and `*money` are the values *pointed to* by the pointers (because `*` *dereferences* a pointer to get what it's pointing to), so `*myMoney = *money;` copies what `money` points to over what `myMoney` points to; the pointers themselves did not change.
- `alpha` is an *array*, which can be *degraded* into a pointer to the first element in the array.
- There's no leak with `alphaPtr` because it wasn't pointing to anything in the first place.
- Yes, `char *alphaPtr = *alpha;` Would have been a much better way to write it, because then `alphaPtr` doesn't spend any time uninitialized. Some compilers will even warn you when you declare uninitialized pointers like the textbook example.
- Using (dereferencing) an uninitialized pointer is a *bad thing* as it results in dreaded *undefined behavior.* Your program may crash immediately, or it may crash much later, or it may simply corrupt your data without telling you anything, and you'll only find it months later, if ever.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the "link" part.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know why I didn't get that when I first saw it in the textbook.  For some reason I was thinking that when it is first declared it reserves a memory slot, and then when we assigned it something later on it unlinked from that memory slot and created another, but that was horribly wrong thinking.

Comment: Pointers are one of the tougher subjects in programming. It requires a leap from the algebra-like "a variable holds a value" mentality, because, if it is a pointer, a variable now merely holds the address of a value, which has no (undergraduate) mathematical parallel (outside computer science, at least).

Answer (score 0):

> This second example causes a memory leak because the original location that *myMoney pointed is no longer accessible. Is this because the memory that used to hold the pointer is now an actual float value instead of a memory address?

The memory location stored in myMoney is now lost. If it was allocated there would be no way to recover its address to deallocate it.

In your second example, arrays are special in that referencing them by name is referencing their address.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with assigning the pointers

```
myMoney = money;
```

is just that if `myMoney` is the only pointer to the value, you have no longer any way to access it.

Comment: So if i never have the pointer point to anything during declaration I'm not losing anything when I actually assign it something later?

Comment: Right, but you probably shouldn't declare a pointer if you don't have a value to assign it. The leak happens when the *last* pointer to an object is lost. Then you no longer now where that object is.

Comment: So if a memory leak happens like that, will the garbage collector reclaim that memory for later use, or is it just taking up space until the program terminates?

Comment: If you have a garbage collector (not standard in C++) it will collect the unused objects. It that case it technically isn't a leak anymore. Otherwise that memory will be unused for the rest of the programs runtime. If you leak a lot of memory, you might eventually run out of usable space...

Comment: C++ has no garbage collector, unless you went and wrote or linked in your own, which is *rarely* the case.

Comment: Is that normal for a programming language to not have a garbage collector?

Answer (score 0):

`myMoney = money` will leak if `myMoney` was previously pointing at dynamically allocated memory. `myMoney` is being assigned a new memory address to point to, so the memory it was originally pointing at will leak if nothing else refers to it anymore so it can freed later.

`alphaPtr = alpha` is not a leak. `alpha` is the actual memory, `alphaPtr` just points to it. Even if `alphaPtr`is assigned to point at something else, `alpha` exists on the stack and will be reclaimed automatically when it goes out of scope.

`char *alphaPtr = *alpha` will not compile. You are trying to assign a `char` to a `char*`, which is not valid.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that *alpha would assign it's address to *alphaPtr.

Comment: What you assign *to* a pointer has nothing to do with whether or not you just leaked memory. The key is: did the pointer's former value point to memory that is not tracked elsewhere? In other words, the *new* value of the pointer doesn't cause the leak, it's the *old* value. Since the old value is invalid in the case of `alphaPtr`, there's no leak.